# Newrelic Application Name set by default to: ExpressionEngine v2.7.0

Tags: ee2, newrelic

Just upgraded to EE 2.7.0. We already use NewRelic for a while to monitor server and application performances.

After upgrading the website to EE 2.7 the site shows up in the Newrelic Application list as: "ExpressionEngine v2.7.0" instead of with the sites name.

Where can I change these, apparently default settings, to show the sites name instead?

Comment: Try here http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/config_editor.html

Answer (score 2):

At the current version, which is 2.7, you can't change the App Name on New Relic, because the name is set on `\system\expressionengine\libraries\Newrelic.php`:

```
public function set_appname()
{
    newrelic_set_appname(APP_NAME.' v'.APP_VER);
}
```

I filled a [bug report](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19712) for this.

---

UPDATE:

This is fixed on EECMS 2.7.1. The name can be set on Admin ‣ System Administration ‣ Output and Debugging or by `$config['newrelic_app_name'] = 'My Site';`.

Comment: So it looks like you COULD change it, by modifying that PHP code. Right? (But the name change would be hardcoded there, rather than changeable through the CP.)

Answer (score 0):

Expression Engine 2.7.1 solved the reported issue by adding $config['newrelic_app_name'] = 'My Site'; to the config file.

However, after upgrading from 2.7.0 to 2.7.1 the site no shows up 3 times in the NewRelic panel as:

- ExpressionEngine v2.7.0 (the old site)
- ExpressionEngine v2.7.1 (the upgraded)
- My Site - ExpressionEngine v2.7.1 (the upgraded + app name in the the config file)